# Python: Simulate search algorithms in network models

Tags: python, networkx, graph-drawing

I am using networkx package to draw power law graphs. I want to simulate a search algorithm on this graph and want to visually see the algorithm move from one node to another on the graph. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

On a mac you could use NodeBox: http://nodebox.net/.

Comment: The new beta version is based on jython and runs on windows aswell: http://beta.nodebox.net/

Answer (score 1):

NetworkX supports drawing using [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org) and [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/). Did you read the [drawing](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/drawing.html)-chapter in its documentation?